# Macbook Pro 13" Retina Late 2013 trackpad replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, display, trackpad, repair

I'm having troubles with replacing the trackpad on my MBPr 13" Late 2013. I've tried two replacement parts. With the first part only click works, but nothing else (I cannot move the mouse pointer at all), and with the second part nothing works at all. I tried the original cable and replacement cables but the results are the same (old trackpad works with the new cables / new trackpads do not work with the old cable...). So I'm kind of baffled because I could not find anybody having troubles doing this. One of the quirks of my makbook may be that it has a Russian keyboard.

I've tried resetting SMC and NVRAM to no avail.

Have anybody had any luck replacing the trackpad? Where did you get the parts? I'm kind of reluctant purchasing yet another one...

Thanks

Comment: I bought this [exact model](http://amzn.to/2DHPFRS) a few weeks ago and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Allan Thanks. This is very useful. I'll probably return the one I've bought and try this one.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, trackpad not working was ruining my day. The easiest fix could be to plug in an external trackpad or mouse to your Mac, but it didn't work for me, even I tried resetting but didn't help.

Then I replaced the trackpad [with a refurbished one](https://shop.rewa.tech/detail/macbook-pro-13-inch-a1989-2018-trackpad-replacement.html) and it is working perfectly.